# "Go To Shopping Cart" opens in a new window

Tags: shopping-cart

After selecting an item in the store, it gives two options: "continue shopping" or "Go To Shopping Cart". If I select the "Go To Shopping Cart", it opens in a new window. How can I fix it? I need it to stay in the same window and just open new page.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Go To Shopping Cart" link might have onclick="window.open()"  property set. In some cases it may be target = "_blank" . That is why it is getting opened in new window. You may turn on template hints from admin to find out the phtml from which it is being rendered and then just remove this property and flush your cache and check again. It must open in same window now.

```
To turn on template path hints in Magento:
Log into the magento back-end admin
Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
Enter your IP in IP restriction text box
Save and refresh page
```

Comment: it was target="_blank" in ajaxsupercart.jq. Solution worked great! Thanks